# Inconsistent behavior of promisified server call through a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a file set inside a directory. I loop through each file, read file content, make a POST request to a remote server and then obtain the response for each call for other tasks. I am facing an inconsistent behavior of getting the response for each file. Let's name these files

```
a.txt, 
b.txt
c.txt
d.txt
e.txt
```

If I use a `console.log` inside the loop, I can see my loop reads each file correctly before making the service call. Problem is with the response of the service call. If I check the response of the service call (I am making 5 service calls), I am getting multiple responses for some files while not getting any response for some. ex: I am checking each response `console.log(details.name);` where I print the name property of each response which should be equal to the file name of the corresponding request. Sometimes I am getting

```
   a
   a
   a
   b
   e
```

And another time

```
   a
   b
   c
   d
   d
```

I am getting 5 responses, but multiple for some files (requests) and nothing for some requests. This is worst if I increase the number of files but I am getting expected output if I use one or two files at a time. I tried each file and every request is giving response individually. What is the reason for this behavior when I try it with multiple files (requests).
Following is the code

```
var request = require("request");
var userDetails;

function initialize(content) {

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    request.post({
      url: 'http://xxx/yyy',
      form: {
        content: content
      }
    }, function(err, resp, body) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(JSON.parse(body));
      }
    })
  });
};

function main() {
  let filenames = fs.readdirSync(dir);
  filenames.forEach(function(filename) {
    console.log(filename);
    let fileContent = fs.readFileSync(dir + filename, 'utf-8');
    var initializePromise = initialize(fileContent);
    initializePromise.then(function(result) {
      details = result;
      .......
      console.log(details.name);
    }, function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
  });
}

main();
```

Comment: Where does the server get the filename from? You're just sending the file content in the POST request.

Comment: Does your server handle concurrent requests correctly?

Comment: What exactly is the `........`, and where is `details` declared? If it's a global variable you're in trouble

Comment: @Barmar I send the content of the file. Response for that content should contains the expected name.

Comment: @Bergi I removed that part due to privacy reasons. I just print the response from the service which still gives responses multiple time for one request while not getting any for some

Comment: @Malintha Does it change anything if you log the `details` immediately (before the probably asynchronous `...` part)?

Comment: @Bergi  No it does not change the result.

Comment: @Malintha Then it seems to be a server issue indeed if you are getting the wrong `result`. Can you post the serverside code, how it gets the name of the file?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I also suspect it. Unfortunately I dont have access to the server code.   Another point is getting correct responses for smaller number of requests. (Ex. 3 requests in a loop.). Considering this, I am looking for a way to make requests with a delay. Can you point me how can I make requests with a delay in between them.

Comment: @Malintha Use `async`/`await` and a `for … of` loop instead of `forEach`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178012/discussion-between-malintha-and-bergi).